# Do these two linear systems have the same solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n$ by $m$ matrix with rank $m$, $n\ge m$.

Let $\vec x$ be an unknown vector of size $m$, $\vec b$ be a vector of size $n$, and $D$ be an $n$ by $n$ diagonal matrix whose all entries are positive.

Does $A^T A \vec x = A^T \vec b$ have the same solution $\vec x$ as $A^T D A \vec x = A^T D \vec b$?